# SSMS change to take data from unzip files to table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2014

I have an script which enters the data into the database through zip files, first moves them after unzipping them and then inserts data from the `CSV`, resulting from unzipping, in the tables. And now I would like to change this script to take the data only from another database and table, but I need to be able to put this data where the `CSV` data went.

```
USE [$(DataTools)];
GO

DECLARE @LoadJob  VARCHAR(64) = '208_table';
DECLARE @LoadStep VARCHAR(64) = 'spMoveUnzipLoad';
DECLARE @PreLoad  VARCHAR(128) = CONCAT('etl.spChangeFileEncodingAsMUZLPreLoad ''', @LoadJob, '''');

DELETE FROM [load].LoadParameters WHERE loadJob = @LoadJob;

EXEC [load].setLoadParameter @LoadJob, @LoadStep, 'copyOrMoveFile'     , 'move';
EXEC [load].setLoadParameter @LoadJob, @LoadStep, 'doNotUnzipFile'     , '0';
EXEC [load].setLoadParameter @LoadJob, @LoadStep, 'FileMask'           , 'data.csv.gz';
EXEC [load].setLoadParameter @LoadJob, @LoadStep, 'firstRow'           , '2';
EXEC [load].setLoadParameter @LoadJob, @LoadStep, 'forLoadFolderName'  , '\ForLoad';
EXEC [load].setLoadParameter @LoadJob, @LoadStep, 'formatFile'         , '\208_Customers.fmt';
EXEC [load].setLoadParameter @LoadJob, @LoadStep, 'loadedFolderName'   , '\Loaded';
EXEC [load].setLoadParameter @LoadJob, @LoadStep, 'notLoadedFolderName', '\NotLoaded';
EXEC [load].setLoadParameter @LoadJob, @LoadStep, 'sourceFolderName'   , '$(SourceFileLocation)';
EXEC [load].setLoadParameter @LoadJob, @LoadStep, 'targetDatasetName'  , 'table_Staging';
EXEC [load].setLoadParameter @LoadJob, @LoadStep, 'targetDatabaseName' , '$(DatabaseName)';
EXEC [load].setLoadParameter @LoadJob, @LoadStep, 'truncate'           , '1';
EXEC [load].setLoadParameter @LoadJob, @LoadStep, 'unzipFolderName'    , '\208_Customers\Unzip';
EXEC [load].setLoadParameter @LoadJob, @LoadStep, 'PostLoadSql'        , 'test_PostLoad';
EXEC [load].setLoadParameter @LoadJob, @LoadStep, 'PreLoadSql'         , @PreLoad;
EXEC [load].setLoadParameter @LoadJob, @LoadStep, 'workingFolderName'  , '\208_Customers\Working';
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--                                                     End of Script
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I change this script to take my data from the tables?
Does it change or does it need to be recreated?

Comment: That scipt doesn't give us any of the "meat", it's just a bunch of `EXEC` statements for a User Stored Procedure we don't have the definition for. Getting SQL Server, however, to perform file system tasks like this seems like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: @Larnu I can't post it because the file it's too big.

Comment: Then how can we hope to tell you how to change the definition of the stored procedure if you can't give us the DDL? But, like I said, this seems like an XY Problem. The Procedure looks like it's trying to be a one size fits all process, which isn't how SQL works.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use your script to create your database structure and at same time load data database content into your structure.
Look at that SSMS export widget to export database (structure and data content).

[image]